# How to check by which column a partition is created in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, database-partitioning

Partition creation is automated but I need to check in Oracle, how the partitions is created according to which column.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can find it in dba_part_key_columns or ALL_PART_KEY_COLUMNS: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/ALL_PART_KEY_COLUMNS.html#GUID-50BBE32C-E57C-49D5-967A-69AF4AA13DC5